# Object.assign() and Spread properties still mutating original

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to assign the value of an array element to an object. After first attempting something like, e.g.`bar = foo[0];` I've discovered that any change to `bar` also changes `foo[0]`, due to having the same reference.

Awesome, thought no one, and upon reading up on *immutability* and the ES6 *Object.assign()* method and *spread* properties, I thought it would fix the issue. However, in this case it doesn't. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Sorry about the *accountTypes* confusion, I fixed the example.
Also, I would like to keep the class structure of *Settings*, so `let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));` is not really what I'm after in this case.

```
//this object will change according to a selection
currentPreset;

//this should remain unchanged
presets: {name: string, settings: Settings}[] = [];


  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.currentPreset = {
      name: '',
      settings: new Settings()
    }

    this.presets.push({name: 'Preset1', settings: new Settings({
        settingOne: 'foo',
        settingTwo: false,
        settingThree: 14
      })
    });

  }

 /**
  * Select an item from the `presets` array and assign it, 
  * by value(not reference), to `currentPreset`.
  * 
  * @Usage In an HTML form, a <select> element's `change` event calls 
  * this method to fill the form's controls with the values of a
  * selected item from the `presets` array. Subsequent calls to this
  * method should not affect the value of the `presets` array.
  *
  * @param value - Expects a numerical index or the string 'new'
  */
  setPreset(value)
  {
    if(value == 'new')
    {
      this.currentPreset.name = '';
      this.currentPreset.settings.reset();
    }
    else
    {
      this.currentPreset = {...this.presets[value]};
      //same as above
      //this.currentPreset = Object.assign({}, this.presets[value]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete or better example? What is `accountTypes`? What is `value`? What is value that you don't wanted to get mutated, what is is before the mutation and what is is after?

Comment: With these operators you are doing a shadow copy of `Settings` which is the same instance in all the updates

Comment: Using object spread or `Object.assign` will create a *shallow copy* only. So mutating properties of that copy will still change the same properties in the original. You may want to try creating a deep copy. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) show a few ways of doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Try this : `let copy = original.map(item => Object.assign({}, ...item));` 
This will create a new object without any reference to the old object `original`

In case if you want to do this for an array try the same with `[]`

```
let copy = original.map(item => Object.assign([], ...item));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a deep copy, this the easiest way:

```
let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
```

Comment: Careful because JSON only stores plain objects, not a particular type of object with a custom protototype.  I can't honestly tell if that matters to the OP's usage since they don't really show enough code to know, but if there's a `Settings` object or any other type of custom object, then this type of deep copy will not preserve the custom object type/prototype.

Comment: @Luis, thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention it but, I do want to preserve the `Settings` object as jfriend00 pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question, but since the object I'm trying not to mutate doesn't have nested properties within, I call the assignment at the property level and the shallow copy here is fine.

```
setPreset(value)
  {
    if(value == 'new')
    {
      this.currentPreset.name = '';
      this.currentPreset.settings.reset();
    }
    else
    {
      this.currentPreset.name = this.presets[value].name;
      this.currentPreset.privileges = Object.assign(new Settings(), 
                                         this.presets[value].settings);
    }
  }
```

A better solution, since I'm creating a `new Settings()` anyway, might be to move this logic to a `Settings` class method and call it in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, and I could not figure out why some of my objects were changing their properties. I had to change my code to avoid mutation. Some of the answers here helped me understand afterwards, such as this great article : https://alistapart.com/article/why-mutation-can-be-scary/

I recommend it. The author gives a lot of examples and useful libraries that can outperform `Object.assign()` when it comes to embedded properties.