# How to copy object properties to another object by reference

Tags: javascript, object, reference, mutate, spread-syntax

I want to be able to bundle the properties of multiple objects into another object by reference, such that when I change the properties in the bundle object it mutates the original objects. I'm using the spread operator to assign the object properties to the new object.

```
objectA = {"key1" : 1, "key2" : 2, "key3" : 3}
objectB = {"key4" : 4, "key5" : 5, "key6" : 6}

bigObject = {...objectA, ...objectB}
bigObject["key1"] = 50;

Logger.log(bigObject["key1"]) //outputs 50
Logger.log(objectA["key1"]) //outputs 1
```

I know Javascript copies by value unless you're copying objects, but I don't want an object of objects, I want an object of properties from other objects. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to construct a much more elaborate object with getters and setters and/or a proxy object which actively applies the changes applied to it to the other objects. There's no way to "reference" primitive values.

Comment: Right, setting something up like this would be sufficiently complicated that I would think that stepping back and evaluating *why* you feel you need this would be fully worth the time.

Comment: @Pointy Right, deceze's suggestion would render the reason I want this pointless. Simply, I have objects that I need to use individually, but I also want to be able to loop through or use Object.values on *all* of them without having to do so for each object individually. This is meant to simplify, not to complicate.

Comment: @Pointy I'm confused though. This fellow talks about using spread to copy array elements to objects, and having problems with the original array elements being mutable on changed to the object. What am I missing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010725/object-assign-and-spread-properties-still-mutating-original

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/476. TL;DR: if the attribute is a mutable object (like an array) and you *mutate* that object, then yeah, it mutates. But numbers can only be *reassigned*, not mutated.

Comment: @RobertM. That question is about a nested structure, but neither your `objectA`/`objectB` nor the `bigObject` are nested. If you had an object containing other objects, shallow cloning would copy the object references - and depending on how you access them, you can either change the reference itself or follow it and mutate the shared target referenced from both original and cloned object.

Comment: @Bergi But this.presets contains primitives e.g. 'foo', false, etc. Then he does this.currentPreset = {...this.presets[value]} and complains that he's seeing a reference copy.

Comment: @deceze Right, but technically what I'm asking about is the object's key/value pairs, not the numbers in them. Presumably changing the value of one of those is akin to changing the value of an array entry, no?

Comment: @RobertM. `this.presets[0]` and `this.currentPreset` are objects, which he is cloning. This object contains another object in its `.settings` property. The OP of that other question failed to clone the `Settings` instance, which is shared by all presets. Notice that `preset.name`, a primitive string, does not have this problem, as `preset` is cloned and the string itself is an immutable value.

Comment: This can be boiled down to this: `let a = 1; let b = a; b = 42;`. Under no circumstances will this change `a`, because `b` can only be *reassigned*. This is different with objects: `let a = []; let b = a; b.push(42)`. This changes both variables, because there's only one object which is being mutated. It doesn't matter that in your case `a` and `b` aren't simply variables but object properties.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I see it now. IRL he would actually be pushing multiple objects into the presets array?

Comment: @deceze I see, so a key/value pair is treated just like a primitive variable?

Comment: The key holds a value. The value is what's important. If this value can be *mutated*, then everything that holds a reference to this value will see the change. It doesn't matter whether that's a key/property or a variable. The value changes or it doesn't. And you cannot change a number. There's no `42.setValue(8)`. Numbers and other primitives are *immutable*. You can only assign a new value to anything that holds such a primitve, like `foo.bar = 8`. And that assigns *only* to that property/variable, not to other variables.

Comment: @deceze "If this value can be mutated, then everything that holds a reference to this value will see the change. It doesn't matter whether that's a key/property or a variable" That's what I'm trying to ask: whether an object can be assigned a *reference* to a key/value pair from another object. If a key/value pair is like a variable, it should be possible to have a reference to it in two different objects. I'm obviously not trying to mutate a number; what would that even mean?

If a key/value pair is a variable, you should be able to stick it into another object and change it from either.

Comment: A key/value ***pair*** isn't like a variable. A key (object property) can hold a value, just like a variable can hold a value. The *left-hand side* (variable/property/key) is the thing that holds a reference to the right-hand side (the value). Yes, I'm simplifying it to say that it always holds *a reference to* a value. This may or may not be true, but that's an implementation detail. The crucial point is whether you can *mutate* that something that the reference points to, or whether you can only assign a new reference to the variable/property/key.

Comment: @deceze Ok...I'm not trying to quibble but obviously I'm trying to have a reference to the same KEY in two different objects. I want to be able to modify the value of the same object property from two different objects. Why do I feel like nobody understands what I'm even asking?

Comment: And what you want is *not possible*. Keys can reference a *value*. Not other keys. End of story.

Comment: @deceze God I miss pointers. It would be cool if Google Apps could use a real language like C++.

Comment: @RobertM. An object reference *is* a pointer. Notice that even in C++ you cannot have two fields of different objects stored in the same location.

Comment: @Bergi Which wasn't what I was ever talking about. Having the same pointer or reference in two different objects was. Having a variable in one object referenced or pointed to in another object is definitely possible in C++. I was basically asking if you could reference one object's key in another object. The answer is no. That's fine. I found the lecture on how you can't mutate numbers amusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
hope below code can help 


const rebuildMergedObject  = () => {

  for (const prop in bigObject) {
    if (bigObject.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !== "sourceObjects") {      
      for (const sourceObject of bigObject.sourceObjects) {
        
        if(sourceObject.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
            sourceObject[prop] = bigObject[prop];
        }
        
      }
    }
  }

};


var objectA = {"key1" : 1, "key2" : 2, "key3" : 3}
var objectB = {"key4" : 4, "key5" : 5, "key6" : 6}
var bigObject = { ...objectA, ...objectB };
bigObject.sourceObjects = [objectA, objectB];
bigObject["key1"] = 50;

rebuildMergedObject();

console.log(bigObject); 
console.log(objectA);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was actually looking for a native way to avoid doing something like that. I always appreciate the time and effort though.